# a type error in Antd React Icon component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

In my React TypeScript project, I've upgraded antd components from version 5.1 to 5.5 and now seeing a compile-time error:

```
 Property 'rev' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Pick<AntdIconProps, "value" | "onChange" | "color" | "content" | "height" | "rotate" | "translate" | "width" | "start" | "hidden" | "cite" | "data" | "form" | 
"label" | ... 349 more ... | "twoToneColor">'.
    25 |   return (
    26 |     <div>
  > 27 |       <ReloadOutlined />
       |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    28 |     </div>
    29 |   );
```

It seems that in the new version of antd, the Icon component has a new required property called "rev".
so now every place in my code I have to provide a value for this prop!
I am curious why this happens in this specific project (other projects and of course antd samples don't have this issue) and if anyone faced it

```
    26 |     <div>
  > 27 |       <ReloadOutlined rev={undefined}/>
    28 |     </div>
```

Answer (score 26):

update react type package to fix your issues

```
npm i -D @types/react@latest
npm i -D @types/react-dom@latest
```

Comment: Hi Amir. I did the same and it worked for me too. tnx

Comment: your welcome, Can I ask you to thumbs up my answer?

Comment: this is a fun game, reacttype at17 break the icons and react types at18 break the Modal

Comment: Upgraded to the latest version shows more errors on other components...

Comment: Hi Amir, Thanks for the fix, it's worked

Answer (score 2):

I have a same problem. When I upgrade the antd version 5.1.0 to 5.4.5.
@ant-design/icon have "rev" props right now.

Comment: did you use the "create-react-app" command to create your project or use something else? I have used Nx. may be its  the Nx's fault

Answer (score 1):

I too had this issue with `@ant-design/icons@5.2.4`.

I'm working on an **SPFx** (SharePoint, v1.17) web part, which has limitations on versions of react / react-dom / typescript.

My code requiring the `rev` attribute on all icons was solved by installing the same major version of `@ant-design/icons` as I have for `antd` (which I had to downgrade from v5.x due to the limitations).

Today (August 2023) when versions 5.x are available, I have these versions in my `package.json`:

```
"@ant-design/icons": "^4.8.0",
"antd": "^4.24.12",
```

Effectively, it was caused by a major version mis-match...

Answer (score 0):

I have also get same error. on github repo, they said upgrade @types/react version but that's does not work. https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-icons/issues/483#issuecomment-1779061345

[image]
[[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by upgrading "@types/react" to version "17.0.11" or above.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions above, but **none of them worked for me**.

I am on react/react-dom 18 and ant 5.

The **only thing that worked** for me was to **downgrade ant icons** to `"@ant-design/icons": "4.3.0"`

Hope this helps someone!

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-icons/issues/483